# Trying to scrape data, but can't scrape it all (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to scrape the number of followers from this page `http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/` but can't seem to pull it. I've tried using `urllib`, `urllib2`, `urllib3`, `selenium` and `beautiful soup`, but have had no luck pulling the followers. Here's what my code looks like currently:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/"

opener = urllib2.urlopen(url)

for item in opener:
    print item
```

How would I go about pulling the number of followers?

Comment: An advice: use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library instead of `urllib2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `selenium` code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/')
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="followers-iframe-container"]/iframe'))
followers_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="member-title"]').text
followers = int(followers_text.split('(')[1].split(')')[0])
```

Last line is kinda rude, so you can change it if you like